# Content Security Policy, Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to create a chrome extension which will get the current URL of open tab then modify it and finally open a new tab with modified URL.

Here are the files

**Manifest.json(V3):**

```
{
  "name": "EDA View Modes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://developer.chrome.com/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./popup.css" />

<head>
    <title>Eda View Mode</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <div class="box">
            <select id="selected">
                <option> JSON </option>
                <option> JSON Text</option>
                <option> Edit </option>
                <option> Expert Edit </option>
            </select>
            <button id="next">
                Next
            </button>
        </div>
    </center>
    <script type="module">
        document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", create_tab);

        function create_tab() {
            chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(async () => {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: 'https://google.com'
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**popup.css:**

```
body {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

I am trying to run a simple script yet getting blocked by CSP! have tried various methods on internet also tried to go through docs but it is all confusing

Comment: This is just basic struct, at least I must be able to create a new tab

Comment: Load a separate popup.js using `<script src=` instead of using inline code. Also note that the popup runs only when shown so your onInstalled event won't run. You need to use it the *background script*.

Comment: @wOxxOm 
Can you please see this [link](https://imgur.com/a/lJSUYEn)

Comment: You're looking at an old error. Click the "Clear all" button and complain in https://crbug.com/1125441.